# I want to save the client_id of the client in the pet table that I am entering at the moment

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

How to save the client_id in another table, I don't know how to save the client_id in my pet table. I am attaching my controller and model code. Thank you very much for your help

Well, I have no idea how to get the client_id, how to put it in the image and store it

database
[mascota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhtwJ.png)

error
Column 'id_cliente' cannot be null

controller

```
if ($this->request->getMethod() == "post") {
        $this->mascota->save([
            'id_cliente' => $this->request->getPost('id_cliente'),
            'id_raza' => $this->request->getPost('id_raza'),
            'nombre' => $this->request->getPost('nombre'),
            'fechaNac' => $this->request->getPost('fechaNac'),
            'sexo' => $this->request->getPost('sexo'),
            'pelaje' => $this->request->getPost('pelaje'),
        ]);

        return redirect()->to(base_url() . '/mascotas');
    } else {

        $raza = $this->raza->where('activo', 1)->findAll();
        $especie = $this->especie->where('activo', 1)->findAll();

        $data = ['titulo' => 'Agregar mascotas', 'raza' => $raza, 'especie' => $especie];

        echo view('header');
        echo view('nav');
        echo view('Mascotas/nuevo', $data);
        echo view('footer');
    }
```

models

```
   protected $table = 'mascota';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $returnType = 'array';
protected $useSoftDeletes = false;

protected $allowedFields = ['id_cliente', 'id_raza', 'nombre', 'fechaNac', 'sexo', 'pelaje','activo'];

protected $useTimestamps = true;
protected $createdField = 'fecha_alta';
protected $updatedField = 'fecha_update';
protected $deletedField = null;

protected $validationRules = [];
protected $validationMessages = [];
protected $skipValidation = false;
```

view

```
form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/mascotas/insertar" autocomplete="off">

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" autofocus required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="fechaNac">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" name="fechaNac" value="" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="especie">Especie</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="id_especie" name="id_especie" value="">
                <option value="">Seleccionar especie</option>
                <?php foreach ($especie as $row) {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="raza">Raza</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="id_raza" name="id_raza">
    
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="sexo">Sexo</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sexo" name="sexo">
                <option value="macho">Macho</option>
                <option value="hembra">Hembra</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <label for="pelaje">Pelaje</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pelaje" name="pelaje" placeholder="Direccion" value="" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: again, please: error as text, not as image! also you should add the part of the error message, which shows the line in your code where it occurs. What you show in the image is not really helpful, it shows where in the library the error triggers.

Comment: Also, it will help if you add the code for the form in the view file.

Answer (score 0):

**error Column 'id_cliente' cannot be null**

Click on structure(Estructura)->Click on "id_cliente" and than click on change. Than click on Null check box and active null can be accept. than save.

It is difficult to understand your language but in simple flow is this.

First add data in `mascota` table. Then using this method and get last inserted id from `mascota` table.

```
$db = db_connect('default'); 
$builder = $db->table('myTable');

$data = [
        'username' => 'darth',
        'email'    => 'd.vader@theempire.com'
];

$builder->insert($data);
$last_id $db->insertID();
```

Using `$last_id` fetch data of `$last_id` and then get value of `id_cliente`. Now using this value insert `id_cliente` value into `pet` table where you want.

Sorry for my poor english. But i hope you understand work flow.